# Improve Web Service Performance

Tags: performance, web-services, web-applications, architecture

I have a web service that takes few arguments, based in on the arguments i need to apply some business logic and return a string value (Old or New), this service will have a frequent hit in production environment (more than 10  request per second). What is the best way of implementing the business logic, I want the service to be very fast and responsive.

1. Store data(conditions) in SQL Table and apply the Business logic in C# and return value.
2. Store data(conditions) in XML file and read file every time and apply the Business logic in C# and return value.
3. Store data(conditions) in SQL Table and write stored procedure to implement the business logic in side the SP and return value to service.

Note : Data(conditions) will not change frequently.

Please suggest the best approach to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way would be push some in-memory cache layer (for example redis) in front of your business logic. The effectiveness of this solution depends on how many different combinations of arguments there are possible. If not many - you can store them all in memory and invalidate cache always if conditions have been changed.

You said that data won't change frequently. My question is - if data (conditions) changes have to be presented to the user in real time, or any delay is possible? If so, you can use reverse proxy caching (varnish for example) - and that should be really fast.

Comment: Yes, Data(conditions) changes has to be presented real time. No delays accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-mature optimization is a dangerous thing. My 2 cents, I would suggest building it out first as quickly and easily as possible. Then 'make it better'. Add in layers etc. Last step is 'make it faster'. You are thinking about the last step before taking the first step.